# Google glass remote debugging (error reporting)

Tags: google-glass, google-gdk

Can we use reporting services like ACRA to debug Google Glass GDK apps run on multiple Glass devices?

Did anyone try this and if he succeeded, which library/service he used for remote debugging?

If I should take special care on something, please mention it as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

YES!

I haven't tried anything bar SILENT mode, because other modes either wouldn't work or may be problematic.